# Heart Rate response to beta-blockers in elderly vs adults

Tags: medications, drug-tolerance, beta-blockers

Beta-blockers act by decreasing the heart rate of the patient. Why is this response decreased in the elderly?

Comment: What's your reference for this claim?

Comment: "Elderly patients may be more sensitive to the blood pressure-lowering effects of beta-blockers than younger patients, and may therefore require lower doses.", according to https://academic.oup.com/eurheartjsupp/article/11/suppl_A/A21/507493#7856785

Comment: @Nate Right, but the question is about rate, not pressure, and a reduced effect of beta blockers rather than increased.

Comment: The way that beta blockers lower blood pressure is through lowering the heart rate. The question starts with the false premise that this response is decreased in the elderly, when in fact it is increased.

Comment: @Nate You are right that the question starts with a false premise; the OP needs to put his research in his stem to show us what he's referring to.  But "The way that beta blockers lower blood pressure is through lowering the heart rate." isn't quite accurate either; they have multiple effects on decreasing overall contractility including inotropy (force) and chronotropy (rate).

Comment: @Nate Not entirely true. BBs also reduce contractility and some relax arteries. For example, I've seen metoprolol drop BP substantially without lowering HR at all in SVT.